# how to get div text with python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

How can I get the text "950" from the div that has neither a ID nor a Class with python selenium?

```
<div class="player-hover-box" style="display: none;">
    <div class="ps-price-hover">
        <div><img class="price-platform-img-hover"></div>
        <div>950</div>
    </div>
```

I dont know how I could access this div and its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `player-hover-box` is an unique class name you can use the following command

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="player-hover-box"]/div/div[2]').text
```

In case there are more products on that page with the similar HTML structure your XPath locator should contain some unique relation to some other element.